# Why doesn't this prime number algorithm say that 2 is not prime?

Tags: python

Why is it that when you input 2 into [this program](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number), it returns "2 is prime"? According to the code, if the remainder of the number divided by `i`, where `i` is any number from (and including) 2 up to the number, is equal to 0, then the number is not a prime number. But the remainder of 2 divided by 2 is 0, so why does the program say that 2 is a prime number?

```
# Python program to check if the input number is prime or not

# take input from the user
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

# prime numbers are greater than 1
if num > 1:
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")

# if input number is less than
# or equal to 1, it is not prime
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Comment: because the number has to be > 1 to be prime? and range(2, 2) will not enter the for loop

Answer (score 3):

because `for i in range(2,2):` will never be true / will not execute.

think about it `range(start, stop)`... the start and stop are the same so it will not enter into the for loop.

2 is a prime number but is the one case where the if statement doesn't need to be computed to determine if its a prime number

[**more details about pythons range function**](http://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

`range(2, 2)` is actually an empty list, so the for loop doesn't iterate at all. It just jumps straight to the `else` clause:

```
>>> num = 2
>>> range(2, num)
[]
>>> for i in range(2, num):
...     print "executing loop"
... else:
...     print "done!"
... 
done!
```

Comment: To nitpick, `range(2, 2)` is an empty `list` in Python 2. In Python 3, it's a `range` object that doesn't describe any terms.